# Move rooftop air conditioner: Is 20cm too close to original location for the bolts to hold strong?

Tags: roof

On a single story flat roof private home I need to move a rooftop air conditioning radiator 20 cm for a solar panel install. Fortunately the sloppy original install left enough electrical cable and refrigerant hose dangling whereas I do not need to concern myself with them. All I need to do is remove the four bolts in the roof, remount in the new location, and seal the original holes.

The house was constructed in 2017. The roof is concrete with a tar-like blanket on top. I do not know how thick the blanket or roof are.

**Is twenty cm enough distance between the old holes and the new holes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 cm is plenty distance between to new and old holes.